# Sum the Count of Min of each column by row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

[image: Screenshot]

I am trying to automate a spreadsheet that will keep a running tally of the most negative topics week over week (kind of like Billboard top 100).

I have tried to get Column A(No.1) to calculate the total number of times each topic had the most negative value for that date.  In the example it should show 2 for topic 1 because it had the most negative value on 4/21 and 4/7, and 1 for topic 6 which had the most negative value on 4/28. 
Column B would do the same but count the topic if it was one of the 3 most negative values.

Column A formula
=SUM(IF(D2=MIN($D$2:$D$7),1,0)+IF(E2=MIN($E$2:$E$7),1,0))

Column B formula
=SUM(IF(D2=SMALL($D$2:$D$7),3)+IF(E2=SMALL($E$2:$E$7),3))

The issue I am running into is that anytime there is a #N/A value in a column the formulas won't work. I was also hoping to not have to continue to add each row to the formula manually as I will need to insert a new column of data each week.

I included a picture of what I have on the left and what I want the formula to produce on the right.
Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: use a `=IFNA()` formula to trap that value and resolve it.

Comment: @Damian, I'm unable to understand that you are considering negative values for `TOPIC 1` is `2` and `1` for `TOPIC 6`, since have `2` and why skipped others when has `TOPIC 4` & `5` has also Negative value !!

Comment: @Damian,, You are already getting Count of Negative Values in `Col  I` then what logic you are trying in `Col H` or `A`?

Comment: Hi Rajesh, I manually typed the values in on the right table to show what I want the formulas to produce for me. Column A should automatically produce count of times the topic has had the most negative value and column B should produce count of times its been one of the 3 most negative values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick to make the functions work past error cells. Note this should work with any type of error in the cell (#DIV/0!, #N/A, etc)

**Sample data:**

[image]

I intentionally made a cell with an error. I put `=2/0` to get a `#DIV/0` error.

So now if I want to get `=MIN()` and not include the error cell I do the following:

```
=MIN(IFERROR(F10:F14,1000))
```

**Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> when entering so it treats the `IFERROR` part as an array**

**Explanation**

The `IFERROR` function substitutes within the array the value 1000 in my case for anything that has an error. Adjust the 1000 to some large value so the other results will always be smaller (basically ignoring it).

Comment: Thanks for the response! This would allow me to identify the single smallest value but how would I use it to count whether that row contained the min value for that column and then expand that to each column to sum the total count.

Comment: You can surround it by what you have above. So for example =IF(D2=MIN(IFERROR(F10:F14,1000)),1,0) still using ctrl shift enter which would place a 1 if it is the minimum and a 0 if not. Make sense?